# Is there any way to pass a variable through a link other than something like "?token=827273"

Tags: php, url, variables

Here's how the app works:

The business will put our recording widget on their website with our embed code. Their users will record a video and after that video has been approved, an email will be sent to the user who recorded the video with a link to the page where the business has added our embed code to display those videos.

The embed code displays a php file, which knows which video to display based on a token value in the url. We add `?token=<?php echo $token ?>` to every url.

Our newest test subject has the url structure, `www.url.com/Page.asp?NavID=3786`, and adding `?token=<?php echo $token ?>` messes up their `NavID` and displays an error.

Without the ability to change their code, is there another way to pass our $token variable (through the link or otherwise) without messing up their variable?

Comment: `www.url.com/Page.asp?NavID=3786&token=<?php echo $token ?>`?

Comment: should be an & not another ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To pass multiple `$_GET` variables simply use `&` between them instead of a second `?`.

```
www.url.com/Page.asp?NavID=3786&token=MyToken
```

Comment: So, I'd write a function that checked if the url already had a $_GET variable. If it did, I'd add "&token=" and if it didn't, I'd add "?token="?

Comment: @Christian Yes, if you have a ? in the url (meaning that a GET variable is already there) then add `&token=` otherwise `?token=`.

Comment: parse_str, http_build_query may be of help

Comment: Why don't you pass the token as an http header and then you will have a cleaner url. I am not sure about your case but normally token are sent for authentication or identification purposes. That is why it will make a cleaner url to remove form there and send it with every request as an http header

Comment: @slash28cu As stated in the question the use case for this is so that the link can be sent in an email which precludes the use of HTTP headers.

Comment: Cool, thanks everyone! I'll mark this answer correct as soon as I'm able.